# Deleted httr, now can't reinstall, or load devtools

Tags: r, devtools, httr

I was trying to install twitteR, but the install failed, saying I needed httr >0.6 and I only had 0.3.

I tried to update httr. However, I seemed to have to 2 versions simultaneously, and when I used library(twitteR) it still said I had httr 0.3 and needed 0.6 (sorry I don't have the exact error messages anymore, and can't replicate due to the problems below.)

So, I deleted httr with `remove.packages('httr')` (this was a mistake).

Now I cannot load devtools

```
> library(devtools)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘httr’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’
```

or install packages

```
install.packages('httr')

'''Some lines skipped'''

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘httr’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’
Execution halted
```

I get the same error message as above when trying to install httr from a tarball with `R CMD INSTALL`.

I'm pretty stuck. Is it time for a clean R install?

And for future reference, how do I update httr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running R as `R --vanilla` fixed the problem.

I could then install httr with

```
install.packages('httr')
```

And then loading devtools works and installing twitteR then works as well.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess -- you have something in your `~/.Rprofile` that's attempting to load `httr` (or a package that uses `httr`) -- since surely, nothing in base R relies on `httr`.

I believe `install.packages()` launches an R sub-process (using the same arguments on load as the current session), which in turn will source that `~/.Rprofile`, and cause the errors you are seeing.

If I am correct, one solution would be to move / comment out your `~/.Rprofile` and restore it after re-installing `httr`. Alternatively, launching `R` with the `--vanilla` flag (to suppress any site / profile loading) should also help in alleviating the problem.

Comment: Yes I had devtools in my Rprofile. As mentioned above, running in vanilla fixed the problem, so I can't now test whether this works.